# How to Close a power point presentation file(.ppsx) automatically?

Tags: powerpoint

I have a power point presentation file with .ppsx format. Now I want to close the file automatically after showing the all slides present in that ppsx file without any mouse interaction. can some one suggest me how can i achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the slide has a transition time of "x" seconds. Make sure "Slide Show", "Set up show" is NOT set to "loop continuously until ESC". And make sure the "End with black slide" feature is unchecked under "Tools", "Options".